# Is there a way to prevent any client connected using web3.js to Quorum from deploying a contract?

Tags: blockchain, quorum

I am planning on using Quorum for a permissioned setup,Is it possible to prevent anyone having a web client and connected to any quorum node deployed in the network from deploying a contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This requires an operator to disable RPC and WS connectivity and route all coms destined to the quorum node through a controlled gateway that connects to the chain through IPC.